# Google maps API - Directions Service

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Im using Google directions service api(Javascript) in my web application.
The client inserts the start and end points -> then gets response with the possible routes (in case there is more the one). When the client selects its relevant route, he sees it rendered on the map by using google.maps.DirectionsRenderer.

**The code:**
Taken as it is from Google Api examples:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel.

**My question:**
How can I get in the server side the client's route selection?
In other words, In the client side - How can I know which is the current selected routes?
(Notice that in the given api example there is only one route available as a result so it is somewhat irrelevant to my question).
Thanks for your time.

Comment: [getRouteIndex()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRenderer) on the client side.  Send it to the server with a post.

Comment: It is indeed the solution. Thank you very much my friend!